# Perl Smart Matching Error

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I am getting a lot of `Global symbol <symbol> requires explicit package name` errors in my code, immediately after the line of code where I have used smart matching. All of those global variables are defined and code worked before using smart matching.

```
if (ref($aActivityErrorStrings) eq "ARRAY" && $sChompedOutput ~~ @$aActivityErrorStrings)
```

The first line of error gives me a hint that there is something wrong with my usage of smart matching. Error line is

```
Status message: Failed: syntax error at common.pm line 320, near "$sChompedOutput ~" Global symbol "$rOutput" requires explicit package name
```

my Perl version is 5.12

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with smart matching?

---

My mistake guys. User of this code was running it on a device which had Perl version 5.8.

Thank you for all the feedbacks. Much appriciated.

Comment: you added a `use 5.010;` in your code to activate smart matching functionality?

Comment: I think we need a [mcve] to diagnose this.

Comment: No, I havent. I didnt add anything like that.

Comment: Put your common.pm on pastebin (or something like that) and I might be able to answer your question

Comment: Only do what @GeorgMavridis suggested if you want your question to get flagged for being off-topic. _Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**._

Answer (score 4):

Error here:

```
if (ref($aActivityErrorStrings) eq "ARRAY"
    && $sChompedOutput ~~ @$aActivityErrorStrings))
                                                 ^
                                                 |
```

You've got an extra closing parenthesis.  Here's proof that your code can work:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;


my $aActivityErrorStrings = [
    "Error1",
    "Error2",
];

my $sChompedOutput = "Error1";

if (ref($aActivityErrorStrings) eq "ARRAY" 
    && $sChompedOutput ~~ @$aActivityErrorStrings) {
    say 'yes'
}

say "@$aActivityErrorStrings";

--output:--
Smartmatch is experimental at 1.pl line 14.
yes
Error1 Error2
```

Comment: Hey, I am sorry that was a typo I made in the stackoverflow. The code is correct in my script

Comment: @Imran, Missing semi-colons will produce errors like that.  Check the lines above the error line for missing semi-colons.  If you want better help, please post the 3 lines after the error message line as well as the 3 lines preceding it.  The error message mentions a variable that doesn't even appear in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

The error

```
Global symbol "$sChompedOutput" requires explicit package name at ...
```

pops up, if you have `$sChompedOutput` undefined.

The following code produces this error:

```
my $aActivityErrorStrings = ["mumu", "Bubu", "hello"];
#my $sChompedOutput = "hello";

if (ref($aActivityErrorStrings) eq "ARRAY" && $sChompedOutput ~~ @$aActivityErrorStrings) {
    print "have hello";
}
```

if you remove the comment before `#my $sChomped...` the error goes away.

Comment: He says `Global symbol <symbol> requires explicit package name` I suspect that the error message's `<symbol>` is to be replaced by a symbol name.

Comment: The code `$x = 3  print $x;` will also produce that error--as already mentioned in the comments. But that isn't the op's code.